# Meteor Mongo Not Getting Collection Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to get a document from a collection, but it doesn't seem to be working.

when i use the find().fetch(), it returns only an empty array. my code is as follows.

```
var users = new Mongo.Collection("users");
console.log(users.find());
var userRecord = users.find().fetch();
var returnUserRecord = {};

if (userRecord.length >0){
    returnUserRecord = {username:userRecord.username, loginHash:userRecord.loginHash};
    console.log("if statement is not complete and the value of the return variable is");
    console.log(returnUserRecord);
}

return returnUserRecord
```

I have checked the database directly and noticed that there is indeed a document in the collection with the command:

```
meteor mongo
```

if it makes any difference, all this code in the in the server js file, and is being called from from the client by: Meteor.Methods()/Meteor.call()

### EDIT 1

i created another collections with new data from the client, and after selecting the correct database, and running the command:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.newCollection1.find()
```

i get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55d1fa4686ee75349cd73ffb"), "test1" : "asdasd", "test2" : "dsadsa", "test3" : "qweqwe" }
```

so this confirms that it is available in the database, but running the following in the client console, still doesnt return the result. (autopublish is installed. i tried removing autopublish and made the appropriate changes to subscribe to the table, but that didnt work either).

```
var coll = new Meteor.Collection('newCollection1');
coll.find().fetch()
```

this returned an empty array. i have also tried the same on the server.js code using:

```
meteor debug
```

but i am still getting an empty array. does anyone know what i might be doing wrong here?

### SOLUTION

the solution for this was to create the collection variable in the Meteor object context. this way it can be accessed from the Meteor context.

i.e.

```
Meteor.coll = new Meteor.Collection('newCollection1');
Meteor.coll.find().fetch();
```

i hope this helps someone. depending on your code you may want to use a different context.

Comment: Should that not be `return users.find().fetch();` and basically nothing else. You define: `var returnUserRecord = {}; return returnUserRecord;` which is of course just an empty object. Only the previous line ( ammended as shown ) actually does anything to retrieve the collection data.

Comment: Have you remove `auto-publish` package from your app? If so, add it to your app, and check whether get correct result or not; if not, what do you get when you run `users.find().fetch()` in browser inspector?

Comment: please see my edit 1. i have tried by adding and removing autopublish. when i removed autopublished i used the information provided by Ryan Wu below.

Answer (score 2):

You don't wait for this subscription to complete, therefore you get empty array.

You should probably read [this](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#subscriptions) or [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) to better understand it.

The thing is you connect users variable to "users" collection, and when you call it, it isn't yet polluted with data (if you don't want to use subscription then maybe use helper - it's reactive so it will return proper value when subscrtiption is finished)

Answer (score 1):

Did you subscribe your `users` collection somewhere?

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("users", function(){
     return Users.find({})
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("users");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this didn't work either. i tried adding the autopublish package back too but still no difference. (apart from a debug message in the console telling me that i dont need publish/subscribe if autopublish package is installed.

Comment: So its the users collection? Did you try ```Meteor.users.find().fetch()``` ?

Comment: This actually works but you need to `return Users.find({})`

Answer (score 0):

First of all some advice: you can not define a collection twice. If you call `new Mongo.Collection("users")` a second time you will get an error. Therefore, it should be a global variable an not inside a method.

What I can see in your code is that you are trying to use an array as if it were an object. `userRecord.username` wont work because `userRecord` has the value of the `fetch()` which returns an array.

You could either change your code to `userRecord[0].username` or loop over the results with `forEach` like so:

```
var users = new Mongo.Collection("users");
console.log(users.find());
users.find().forEach(function(singleUser){
    console.log(EJSON.stringyfy(singleUser));
}
```

in order to return the first user, you would be better of using `findOne` which returns the first object in the result.

Comment: thanks, but i still get 'undefined' back. INPUT: coll.find().forEach(function(singleUser){
    console.log(EJSON.stringyfy(singleUser));
})
OUTPUT: undefined

Comment: this is the same as 'userRecord[0].username', which is expected because the returned result from 'users.find().fetch()' is '[]' (empty array).

Comment: if the singleUser is undefined, that means that your collection does not contain any users. In order to verify this, you should run the code in debug mode and try to query the users collection in the console. This way you will know what is going on and you will be able to trouble shoot.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds logical and that's what I would have assumed, but when I query the database directly with "meteor mongo" I can see the record. Please see "edit 1" section above where i created a new collection.

Comment: if you run the code in debug, you will probably see what is going wrong. You can try out different ways to query. For example users.find({}) instead of users.find() and you can also try to users.insert({...}) and check if you get something in the collection. Your issue is either due to a typo in the find or you are not checking the same collection in meteor mongo as you query in your code or your application is called with MONGO_URL environment variable set

Comment: thanks! That wasn't the answer but it helped. I'm going to confirm a few more things and I'll update this thread with the answer in a moment.